# What does the LDAP response tuple (97, []) mean?

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap

I am using python-ldap to try to authenticate against an existing Active Directory, and when I use the following code:

```
import ldap
l = ldap.initialize('LDAP://example.com')
m = l.simple_bind_s(username@example.com,password)
```

I get the following back:

```
print m
(97, [])
```

What does the 97 and empty list signify coming from a Microsoft Active Directory server?

I gather this is a successful authentication since it doesn't error (which it does if you use the wrong password or non-existent username), but I'd like to know if the tuple means something useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/218185), this is:

```
LDAP_REFERRAL_LIMIT_EXCEEDED      0x61   The referral limit was exceeded.
```

Probably

```
ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
```

could help.

Comment: That helps.  The LDAP standard indicated that 91-120 (I think that was the range) were "vendor specific" or some such, and I couldn't find the Microsoft page you pointed to.  Ainab's response is also useful.

Answer (score 6):

The first item is a status code (97=success) followed by a list of messages from the server.
See [here](http://www.packtpub.com/article/installing-and-configuring-the-python-ldap-library-and-binding-to-an-ldap-directory) in the section **Binding**.

Comment: Your link is to a spam re-embedding of this article: http://www.packtpub.com/article/installing-and-configuring-the-python-ldap-library-and-binding-to-an-ldap-directory

Comment: @polm23 - in future just do a suggested edit on the post and explain why.

Answer (score 0):

here is a forum thread that explains the error and provides work around. 
http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t612838-pythonldap-operations-error.html