# LDAP in Django 1.5 & Python 3

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, active-directory, ldap

I am using Django 1.5 and Python 3. I am new to Django & LDAP in general.

I am including the following configuration (modified for my case) in my `settings.py` file, which was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860943/importing-ldap-users-into-django-database):

```
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://example.fr"

AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = 'cn=a_user,dc=example,dc=fr'
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD=''
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch('ou=users,dc=example,dc=fr', ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, '(uid=%(user)s)')
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch('ou=groups,dc=example,dc=fr', ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, '(objectClass=groupOfNames)')

AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE = ActiveDirectoryGroupType()

#Populate the Django user from the LDAP directory
AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
    'first_name': 'sAMAccountName',
    'last_name': 'displayName',
    'email': 'mail'
}


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

However, I have also followed the discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-auth-ldap/T80u61-ZM5k) where it says that, the `django-auth-ldap` module is not ported to Python 3.

I have a couple of questions:

1. What are the module imports that need to go into the `settings.py` file in order to get the configuration above to work?
2. Which of those imports are not available for Python 3?
3. Is it possible to get LDAP-based authentication going for Django with Python 3? Is it some modification of the approach above, or something different?

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you got your answer through the linked discussion, but I'll post it here to help anyone who comes across this question.

python-ldap does not support Python3 yet, but there is a fork which does:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/rbarrois/python-ldap.git@py3
```

It looks like the changes have been accepted upstream, but it was easier to follow the instructions at django-auth-ldap to install that fork than to figure out what version at pypi would have the changes.

You also need to install django-auth-ldap:

```
pip install django-auth-ldap
```

At this point, most of your code should work with two imports:

```
import ldap
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch
```

You will probably also need to import the ActiveDirectoryGroupType from somewhere, but I haven't ever used that.

Based on the discussion, python-ldap is an old and fragile code base. I have been very happy with python3-ldap, and hope that django-auth-ldap will move to that module in the future.

http://pythonhosted.org/python3-ldap/

Comment: Thanks, I actually had difficulty following the linked discussion (and abandoned it). I will try your suggested steps and report back.

Answer (score 4):

A late follow up, but a better option for Python 3 may now be available. I have started using this Django app for my needs:

https://github.com/etianen/django-python3-ldap

It runs great with Python 3 and the package ldap3. I've only tested against OpenLDAP so far.